# Show that B and B' have the same orientation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have troubles with my homework. I have no idea on where to start:

Show that B and B' have the same orientation if: $ sgn(\sigma)=\pm 1$

$$
B:=(b_1,...,b_n) \\
B':=(b_{\sigma(1)},...,b_{\sigma(n)})
$$

Comment: Avoid questions with "I have no idea on where to start". Instead, start searching yourself.

Comment: Ah yeah now I got it. Your help was very much appreciated!
Just kidding, I spent already 3h on this one. I'm lost.

Comment: Then spend at least $1$ minute reading some related posts, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199509/intuition-for-bases-having-the-same-orientation). Did you search already?